# Union closure of a set of five finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been playing with some basic set theory while looking at the [Union-closed sets conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture).

Pretty basic question, but given four finite sets $A,B,C,D, \mathcal{Y}$ where
$$A \cup B = C \cup D = \mathcal{Y}$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are all distinct, but $A, C$ are not necessarily disjoint from $B,D$, respectively. Also, $|\mathcal{Y}| > |A| \geq |B| \geq |C|  \geq |D|$.

If it must be the case that these five sets are union closed, what can I say about $A \cup C$ and $B \cup D$?

Intuitively,  I believe that $A \cup C = B \cup D = \mathcal{Y}$, but I am not sure. Any help, or a point in the right direction would be helpful.

Thank you.

Edit:

Clearly, my intuition was incorrect. Having seen the counterexample, it seems more accurate to say that $A \cup C  = \mathcal{Y}$ or $C \subset A$, I will work with this and see what I get.

Glad I could throw an idea out and have someone point out an example I had not thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is not right. Let:

$$A = \lbrace 1,2,3,4\rbrace\ B=\lbrace 2,3,4,5\rbrace,\ C=\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace ,\ D = \lbrace 4,5 \rbrace $$

Then $A,B,C,D$ are all distinct, $A\cup B = C\cup D = \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5\rbrace =: \mathcal{Y}$.

And $|\mathcal{Y}| > |A| \geq |B| \geq |C|  \geq |D|$. So all your hypothesis are achieved.

You can see that the union of any two given sets of the family belongs to it, but:

$$A\cup C \neq B\cup D$$

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I might be able to say that $A \cup C \not= \mathcal{Y} \implies C \subset A$ in this case, and that seems to make sense. Glad you pointed this out to me, I was going in the wrong direction, but if the new hypothesis holds where we say subset instead of equality, that could be useful.

Comment: @WilliamHenryLanghoff You can say that if $C \subset A \Rightarrow A\cup C \neq \mathcal{Y}$ but I'm not sure about the reverse implication...
Glad I could help!